# checkboxes tiny and unclickable in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

For some reason the check-boxes on this form are not clickable and are very, very, tiny using google chrome.  When using firefox the checkboxes work great.  I'm not exactly sure what to look for...  It's really strange!!!  Is there something wrong with the way I'm using `<form>`?  When I use inspector even if I disable all css the checkboxes are still tiny.  not sure what is going on.  reset browser cache etc.  really could use some help.

**HTML:** http://pastebin.com/Pt6YgGP7:

**CSS:** http://pastebin.com/WHap5Vmh

**Screenshot:**

[image: Tiny checkboxes]

```
    <div class="categories">
    <button class="tyl_category" id="category1">Category1</button>          
    </div>  
    <form name ="things-you-like-form" class="sub-categories" action="things-you-like">

        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls category" id="form-category1">
                Select from Category 1
                <input type="checkbox" name="tyl_picked1" value="c1s1">
                <label for "category1-subcategory1">1.1</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="tyl_picked1" value="c12">
                <label for "category1-subcategory2">1.2</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="tyl_picked1" value="c1s3">
                <label for "category1-subcategory3">1.3</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="tyl_picked1" value="c1s4">
                <label for "category1-subcategory4">1.1</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end for-each sub-categores -->


    </form>


</div>
```

JS

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').each(function() { this.reset() });
    var progress = 0;

    $categories = $('.categories');
    $sub_categories = $('.sub-categories');

    $(document).on('click','.tyl_category', function(e) {

        $form = $('#form-'+this.id);
        console.log(this.id);
        $categories.hide('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 250, function() {
            $sub_categories.show();
            $form.show('slide', { direction: 'right' },250);
        });
    });

    $(document).on('click','input[type="checkbox"]', function (e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $progress_bar = $('#tyl_progress_bar');
        if ($this.is(':checked')) {
            progress +=1;
        } else {
            progress -=1;
        }
        $progress_bar.text('Step '+progress+'/5');
        $progress_bar.css({width: (progress*25)+"%"});  
        $form = $this.parent('div');
        $form.hide('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 250, function() {
            $sub_categories.show();
            $categories.show('slide', { direction: 'right' },250);
        });


    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/At7TA/ it seems to work.. can you also post your css or more code?

Comment: Your form has no `method`, but that shouldn't case this. You forgot the = sign after your for attribute in your labels.

Comment: @BeNdErR There's a lot going on, is there anything specific that comes to mind that would cause this?  I can post more code, but there is a LOT and don't want to bloat the page

Comment: We need to see your CSS. Stop your CSS from working. If it fixes the problem, it's a CSS issue.

Comment: could you post a screenshot?

Comment: full html is here: http://pastebin.com/Pt6YgGP7

Comment: using bootstrap/jquery/epsilon frameworks. here is the custom css:http://pastebin.com/WHap5Vmh

Comment: Screenshot: http://imgur.com/UMK3JZ5

Comment: Have you tried to remove all CSS as suggested by  PHPglue? Could be a CSS rule using `-webkit-apperance` but i don't see it in code you have posted

Comment: hmm it might be from jquery ui or epsilon frameworks, I'll start taking out css and see what happens.

Comment: @MatthewA.McFarland I'm having this same problem.  Did you ever discover the source of the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too and had to set the checkbox height and width:

```
.make-checkbox-reasonable-height {
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
}

<div class="col-sm-2">
    <input asp-for="MyCheckBox" class="form-control input-control make-checkbox-reasonable-height" />
</div>
```